# RoR, has_one, or maybe I need something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a `Status` table (with an id and a name column), it has rows like "Pending", "Done", etc. I also have a `Data` table with things like id, name, comment, etc. I want each Data row to have a status, so the logical thing looks like putting a status_id into the `Data` table, but how do I represent that in RoR? has_one seems to be working the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one and read this paragraph `2.7 Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one`

Answer (score 1):

You put `has_one :data` in `Status` model

You put `belongs_to :status` in `Data` model

If your table doesn't have the references yet, I suggest :

```
rails g migration AddStatusToDatas status:references
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

You would try to use [enumerated_attribute](https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute) plugin. It's good solution if you have fixed statuses.